# Could someone help solve my Windows 10 DRIVER_POWER_STATE_FAILURE BSOD's on wake

Tags: windows-10, bsod, ntoskrnl.exe

Windows 10 64-bit, upgraded in-place from Windows 7. Intel Core i5-4690K (not overclocked), 16Gb RAM, and an Nvidia GeForce GTX 660 Ti (latest driver) on a Gigabyte Z97MX-Gaming 5 motherboard. Nearly every time I wake the computer from sleep, I get a `DRIVER_POWER_STATE_FAILURE` BSOD after a minute of blank screens.

The problem is being caused by driver `ntoskrnl.exe`, according to BlueScreenView, or by `dxgkrnl.sys` according to WinDbg - "A driver has failed to complete a power IRP within a specific time."

Here's the .dmp from Minidump: https://www.dropbox.com/s/v3pnwlamjnotkly/100115-6500-01.dmp?dl=0

Here's the MSINFO output: https://www.dropbox.com/s/1x2qi52d0kddqvp/msinfo32.nfo?dl=0

And here's the WinDbg results (from following [this guide](http://www.instructables.com/id/How-to-Analyze-a-BSOD-Crash-Dump/?ALLSTEPS)): https://www.dropbox.com/s/q4fx9ctxv3pj1os/windbg%20output.TXT?dl=0

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the dump, your NVIDIA graphic driver for your GPU (VEN_10DE&DEV_1183) causes the crash:

```
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Bugcheck Analysis                                    *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

DRIVER_POWER_STATE_FAILURE (9f)
A driver has failed to complete a power IRP within a specific time.
Arguments:
Arg1: 0000000000000003, A device object has been blocking an Irp for too long a time
Arg2: ffffe000ef7a2320, Physical Device Object of the stack
Arg3: fffff802d40f7990, nt!TRIAGE_9F_POWER on Win7 and higher, otherwise the Functional Device Object of the stack
Arg4: ffffe0010734b010, The blocked IRP

Debugging Details:
------------------

Implicit thread is now ffffe000`f6b69600
*** WARNING: Unable to verify timestamp for nvlddmkm.sys
*** ERROR: Module load completed but symbols could not be loaded for nvlddmkm.sys

SYSTEM_SKU:  To be filled by O.E.M.

SYSTEM_VERSION:  To be filled by O.E.M.

BIOS_DATE:  05/30/2014

BASEBOARD_PRODUCT:  Z97MX-Gaming 5

BASEBOARD_VERSION:  x.x

BUGCHECK_P1: 3

BUGCHECK_P2: ffffe000ef7a2320

BUGCHECK_P3: fffff802d40f7990

BUGCHECK_P4: ffffe0010734b010

DRVPOWERSTATE_SUBCODE:  3

FAULTING_THREAD:  f6b69600

CPU_COUNT: 4

CPU_MHZ: dac

CPU_VENDOR:  GenuineIntel

CPU_FAMILY: 6

CPU_MODEL: 3c

CPU_STEPPING: 3

CUSTOMER_CRASH_COUNT:  1

DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  WIN8_DRIVER_FAULT

BUGCHECK_STR:  0x9F

PROCESS_NAME:  System

CURRENT_IRQL:  2

ANALYSIS_VERSION: 10.0.10240.9 amd64fre

LAST_CONTROL_TRANSFER:  from fffff802d22bb0d0 to fffff802d23c8c76

STACK_TEXT:  
00 nt!KiSwapContext
01 nt!KiSwapThread
02 nt!KiCommitThreadWait
03 nt!KeWaitForSingleObject
04 dxgkrnl!DpiRequestIoPowerState
05 dxgkrnl!DpiFdoSetAdapterPowerState
06 dxgkrnl!DpiFdoHandleDevicePower
07 dxgkrnl!DpiDispatchPower
08 nvlddmkm
09 0x0
0a 0x0
0b 0x0


STACK_COMMAND:  .thread 0xffffe000f6b69600 ; kb

FOLLOWUP_IP: 
dxgkrnl!DpiRequestIoPowerState+a2
fffff802`0247f682 8bd8            mov     ebx,eax

SYMBOL_STACK_INDEX:  4

SYMBOL_NAME:  dxgkrnl!DpiRequestIoPowerState+a2

FOLLOWUP_NAME:  MachineOwner

MODULE_NAME: dxgkrnl

IMAGE_NAME:  dxgkrnl.sys

DEBUG_FLR_IMAGE_TIMESTAMP:  55bebfed

IMAGE_VERSION:  10.0.10240.16425

BUCKET_ID_FUNC_OFFSET:  a2

FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  0x9F_3_POWER_DOWN_dxgkrnl!DpiRequestIoPowerState

BUCKET_ID:  0x9F_3_POWER_DOWN_dxgkrnl!DpiRequestIoPowerState

PRIMARY_PROBLEM_CLASS:  0x9F_3_POWER_DOWN_dxgkrnl!DpiRequestIoPowerState

ANALYSIS_SOURCE:  KM

FAILURE_ID_HASH_STRING:  km:0x9f_3_power_down_dxgkrnl!dpirequestiopowerstate

FAILURE_ID_HASH:  {1f04a7b8-25d5-85a2-98d6-ff5f5302be37}

Followup:     MachineOwner
---------

0: kd> !podev ffffe000ef7a2320
Device object is for:
  DriverObject ef7ea820
Current Irp 00000000 RefCount 0 Type 00000023 AttachedDev ffffe000ef78bdb0 DevFlags 00001040
Device queue is not busy.
Device Object Extension: ffffe000ef7a2a68:
PowerFlags: 00000010 =>SystemState=0 DeviceState=1
Dope: 00000000:
0: kd> !devstack ffffe000ef78bdb0
  !DevObj           !DrvObj            !DevExt           ObjectName
  ffffe000f278c040  \Driver\nvlddmkm   ffffe000f278c190  InfoMask field not found for _OBJECT_HEADER at ffffe000f278c010

> ffffe000ef78bdb0  \Driver\ACPI       ffffe000ee094c70  
  ffffe000ef7a2320  \Driver\pci        ffffe000ef7a2470  Cannot read info offset from nt!ObpInfoMaskToOffset

!DevNode ffffe000ef78baa0 :
  DeviceInst is "PCI\VEN_10DE&DEV_1183&SUBSYS_35561458&REV_A1\4&1286464&0&0008"
  ServiceName is "nvlddmkm"
0: kd> lmvm nvlddmkm
Browse full module list
start             end                 module name
fffff802`02740000 fffff802`03233000   nvlddmkm T (no symbols)           
    Loaded symbol image file: nvlddmkm.sys
    Image path: \SystemRoot\system32\DRIVERS\nvlddmkm.sys
    Image name: nvlddmkm.sys
    Browse all global symbols  functions  data
    Timestamp:        Sun Sep 13 23:12:24 2015
```

Report it to nVIDIA in their [forums](https://forums.geforce.com/default/board/33/geforce-drivers/) and as a workaround try to disable all power saving options you can in the Geforce driver.

Comment: Here's the link over on the nVidia forums, for future reference: https://forums.geforce.com/default/topic/881740/near-constant-bsod-when-waking-windows-10-from-sleep-gtx-660-ti-driver-at-fault/#4683692

Comment: Seeing as I'm getting such _wonderful_ support over at the nVidia forums, perhaps I'll ask here... does this seem like something that might occur if the PSU isn't quite powerful enough? Occasional BSOD on waking from sleep, as well as sometimes in War Thunder. Other games (eg. Far Cry 3, C&C4, etc) have no issues.

Comment: which PSU do you have?

Comment: Thermaltake Litepower 600W. Also, had my first crash in Far Cry 3 last night. :-/

Comment: this PSU should be enough for a 660Ti.

Comment: Ok, figured out that my post over in Nvidia's forums has never been seen due to them thinking I'm a spammer. https://forums.geforce.com/default/topic/845400/forum-feedback/post-here-if-your-posts-amp-replies-are-hidden/?offset=3#4703529